# Re: Intel IME\physical-access exploits - Has a Manufacturer ever (unintentionally) released malware-infected PC Components?

Tags: malware, virus, hardware, usb

Given the discovery that [Intel's IME can be hacked by USB (since 2008)](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/65327/hacking/intel-management-engine-flaw-hack.html), I started researching hardware level exploits - like the [Stuxnet USB attack on Iran's Nuclear plant](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2015/ph241/holloway1/) and I'm curious about the likelihood of these physical-access penetrations becoming large-scale.

Many people I've spoken with say my fears are unfounded because "*No one would stick a random USB flashdrive into their PC.*" - but I disagree - isn't that exactly how Stuxnet was delivered? (Someone found a USB drive laying around, so they plugged it in to see what was on it)

That said, what about **manufacturer-level entry points**? As in - how likely is it that someone would infect a batch of Flashdrives at the manufacturer, and those be shipped out to consumers and retail outlets? (Seems like a nifty way to start a botnet)

Are there any known cases of manufacturers shipping out infected hardware, flash drives or other PC components/peripherals?

Comment: It's not just the Iranians.  That's also how the DoD was attacked.

They're not USB drives, but I recall Sony shipping CDs with rootkits on them a while ago.  More info is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal

Comment: Here's one example: http://www.zdnet.com/article/ibm-warns-of-malware-on-usb-drives-shipped-to-customers/

Comment: Irons and kettles with 'undocumented' wifi chips: https://thehackernews.com/2013/11/russia-finds-spying-microchips-planted_1.html